# DuckDuckGo App Tracking Protection

Tags: applications, privacy

As you might be aware `duckduckgo` recently launched there app tracking protection to block hidden trackers account apps in the device.
Link: [app-tracking-protection](https://spreadprivacy.com/app-tracking-protection-open-beta/)

Now, I have been running this service for about 10 days, it seems to block the trackers for the other app. but I have few doubts as there are some app that never appear in trackers.

[image]

**Doubts I have:**

1. Does duckduckgo not user trackers(as it never appears in the list) or is there app whitelisted.
2. Does anyone know any other service similar to this.

Comment: You can check DDG's trackers using [Tracker Control](https://trackercontrol.org/) app. I'm assuming DDG's app uses localhost VPN to sniff traffic. In that case, only one VPN can run (Tracker Control also uses localhost VPN).

Comment: @Firelord , yes DDG's app uses localhost VPN. Thanks , I will give it a try if I can find anything